# Reference book on Ethereum?

Tags: protocol, tutorials

When we search "Ethereum" keyword in Google or Amazom, we find a lot of books on this topic. I bought some kindle books, however they mostly talk about basic topics that are usually repeated in most of books: ex. General explanation about Blockchain technology, a bit about Bitcoin, differences of Ethereum with Bitcoin etc...

I'm looking for a ***reference book on Ethereum*** which explain almost ***everything*** on this topic. Does someone know such a book on Ethereum ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The book named "**Mastering Blockchain: Distributed ledger technology, decentralization, and smart contracts explained, 2nd Edition**" by Imran Bashir, is what I believe to be the closest you'll find to a reference type of book on Blockchain (it talks a lot about Ethereum-related development) at given moment.

However, Andreas Antonopoulos is working on a book called "**Mastering Ethereum**" which should be due to release at the end of 2018.

The book by Imran Bashir is available on amazon and the one by Andreas Antonopoulos is available for pre-order.

### Update

Andreas M. Antonopoulos and Gavin Wood published Mastering Ethereum on the 1st of December 2018. Check it out for free on [GitHub](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook) or on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1491971940) if you want to support the authors for their hard work.